# How to get the information of the client in rest service

Tags: web-services, rest, client

I have created a Rest service. In this service I want to know which client is calling the service. Is there any method to check the properties or information of the client.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you exactly mean by "which client". I see two things:

- **The terminal kind**. This can be known using the [`User-Agent`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.43) header if set.
- **The authenticated user** using the [`Authorization`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.8) header. The content in this header allows to get the corresponding user. This allows to authenticate requests. In this case, this link could help you: https://templth.wordpress.com/2015/01/05/implementing-authentication-with-tokens-for-restful-applications/.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry